# Efficiently rendering onClick API call buttons in a table without unnecessary fetches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-query

What is the most efficient way to create action buttons on a table with onClick API calls, without causing unnecessary automatic data fetching for all rows?

I have already tried initialising the button with the row value, but this caused API calls to be triggered for every row, even if the button wasn't clicked. How can I ensure that the API call is only made when the corresponding button is clicked, without causing excessive re-rendering of the entire button set?

I created a [stackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-9qbtvc?file=src/components/table.tsx) that replicates the issue I'm facing, and I have included all the solutions I have tried so far. However, none of them seem to work as intended.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated!

---

I'm also adding my code here if you prefer it this way:

##### Defining my columns: <sub>(in the table component)</sub>

```js
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<RouterOutputs['lines']['get'][0]>();
const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor('phoneNumber', {
    header: 'Phone Number',
    cell: (info) => formatPhoneNumber(info.getValue()),
  }),

  // Actions options 1
  // Problem: This makes an api call for the every row everytime.
  columnHelper.display({
    header: 'Actions',
    id: 'actions',
    cell: (info) => (
      <div className="dropdown dropdown-top">
        <div tabIndex={0}>
          <button className="btn btn-accent btn-sm btn-square">
            <DotsThreeVertical size={24} />
          </button>
        </div>
        <ActionsMenu phoneNumber={info.row.original.phoneNumber} />
      </div>
    ),
  }),

  // Actions option 2
  // Problem: The menu will get rerendered for all the elements on every click
  //          and sometime two clicks will be required to see the menu.

  // columnHelper.display({
  //   header: 'Actions',
  //   id: 'actions',
  //   cell: (info) => (
  //     <div className="dropdown dropdown-top">
  //       <div tabIndex={0}>
  //         <button
  //           onClick={() =>
  //             setSelectedPhoneNumber(info.row.original.phoneNumber)
  //           }
  //           className="btn btn-accent btn-sm btn-square"
  //         >
  //           <DotsThreeVertical size={24} />
  //         </button>
  //       </div>
  //       <ActionsMenu phoneNumber={selectedPhoneNumber} />
  //     </div>
  //   ),
  // }),

  columnHelper.accessor('simNumber', {
    header: 'SIM Number',
    cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
  }),

  /* ...more columns */
];
```

##### Creating the table:

```js
const table = useReactTable({
    pageCount: !linesCount ? 1 : Math.ceil(linesCount / pagination.pageSize),
    columns: columns,
    data: data,
    state: {
      pagination,
    },
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    manualPagination: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
  });
```

##### ActionsMenu component:

```js
export default function ActionsMenu({ phoneNumber }: { phoneNumber: string }) {
  const lineInfoQuery = api.lines.getActions.useQuery({ phoneNumber });
  if (lineInfoQuery.isLoading) {
      // render loading
  }

  const isError =
    lineInfoQuery.isError ||
    lineInfoQuery.data === undefined ||
    typeof lineInfoQuery.data == 'string';

  if (isError) {
    // render error
  }

  const lineInfo = lineInfoQuery.data as LineInfoResponse;
  const actions = [
    {
      id: 'swap',
      available: lineInfo.can_sim_swap,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 'refresh',
      available: lineInfo.can_refresh,
      ...
    {
      id: 'update',
      available: lineInfo.can_update,
      ...
    },
  ];

  return (
    // render available buttons 
  );
}
```

Comment: Add some `data-` attributes to your buttons to describe them. Add a global click handler for all buttons that is driven off the aforementioned `data-` attributes (something like `event.target.dataset.recordId`)

Comment: Thanks for the help!
@AdamH I will still eventually need to provide the props with the fetched data to the menu, and that will cause the columns to be recalculated and will result in ui not behaving. 

As I understand, your solutions solves the part of the automatic fetching, correct?